# CakePHP3 Tree bahavior + translation behavior

Tags: php, tree, cakephp-3.0

Im trying to create a list of categories that need to be translated and display them as a tree structure. But so far no luck, i got tree structure going but when ever i create new category it adds up to the tree but wont display the name because its being translated with i18n and stores in diffirent table...

$categories_list = $this->Categories->find('treeList')->toArray();

This var stores tree it self with names that i have in Categories Table...

$categories_list = $this->Categories->find('translations')->toArray();

And this one gives me the actual translated categories, anyone has any idea how to combine them, CakePhp3 is a new thing for me and i cant find to much documentation about combining those two behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get translated fields into tree list you need to add TranslateTrait into Category entity, it should look like this:

> [Link to CookBook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html#saving-multiple-translations) about Translate behaviour and TranslateTrait

```
/src/Model/Entity/Category.php
```

```
<?php

    namespace App\Model\Entity;

    use Cake\ORM\Behavior\Translate\TranslateTrait;
    use Cake\ORM\Entity;

    class Category extends Entity{

        use TranslateTrait;

        //translation field must be accessible
        protected $_accessible = [
            'translations' => true,
        ];

    }
```

---

Then you should stack multiple finder methods to achieve your goal, one for Translation Behaviour and one Tree Behaviour

> [Link to CookBook](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.Datasource.QueryInterface.html#_find) about how to stack multiple finder methods

```
/src/Controller/ArticlesController.php
```

```
    use Cake\I18n\I18n;     

    public function foo(){

        /***
        *
        *   1) use translation finder
        *   2) use treeList finder
        *   3) give to treeList finder the translated value to use in the output array as valuePath param
        *
        ***/

        $tree_list = $this->Articles->Categories
            ->find('translations')
            ->find('treeList', ['valuePath' => '_translations.' . I18n::getLocale() . '.title'])
            ->toArray();

    }
```

---

You can leave **I18n::getLocale()** as it is to automatically get the tree list in current language or replace it with the language you prefer.